# SSL not working in nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I'm running an Ubuntu 20.04 instance with nginx. My server block is as follows. (masked the original domain though)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    
    
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

The port 443 is enabled, and the site's working without SSL. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit 1: The page is loading when accessed with http but results in a 'The connection has timed out' error when accessing with https.

Comment: Do you mean that when you access the website through port 80 doesn't redirect to HTTPS?

Comment: No, it doesn't redirect, but that's because I have kept it that way for now. The page is loading when accessed with http but results in a 'The connection has timed out' error when accessing with https.

Comment: as you said, port 443 is in listening mode on the server. make sure you are able to telnet from your network(outside of the server) to port 443 and check whether session is opened. This is to make sure no firewall is dropping SSL traffic to your server

Comment: @ZarehKasparian Thank you that was the issue. It wasn't connecting. I'm using an AWS lightsail instance and enabled the ports through ufw. But I had to add a rule to the IPv4 firewall in the lightsail console. Now, it's working. Thank you.